# Checking existence of optional parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have three optional parameters `param1`, `param2` and `param3`. User can pass any number of them in any combination.

I can check if the param key is present like below if all three are passed:

```
  def index
     return unless params.key?(:param1) && params.key?(:param2) && params.key?(:param3) 
     @test = Model.where(param1: params[:param1], 
                         param2: params[:param2],
                         param3: params[:param3])
  end
```

But I don't want to repeat the same code for other conditions like if only `param1` is passed or `param1` and `param2` is passed or same param can be passed twice e.g.:

```
http://localhost:1000/orders?param1[]=abc&param1[]=
```

(passing abc and blank value for same param1)

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"pram1"=>["abc", ""], "format"=>:json, "controller"=>"orders", "action"=>"index", "order"=>{}} permitted: false>
```

Is there a better way to check the existence of these params so I don't have to repeat the same code?

Comment: Is your code working fine ? I think `return unless params.key?(:param1) && params.key?(:param1) && params.key?(:param1)` should be `return unless params.key?(:param1) || params.key?(:param2) || params.key?(:param3)`

Comment: Well thats just one case if all 3 params are passed and the where clause is based on what is passed.

Comment: I think there is a typo `param1` in each case assuming it should be `param2` & `param2` but in your code it will return even when `param1 & param2 present but param3 is absent`

Comment: You are right. thanks updated.

Answer (score 1):

If the requirements are:

- Handle only parameters named `param1`, `param2` or `param3`.
- Handle only the first value even if multiple values are passed with a same key.

This might work.

```rb
conditions = params.select {|k|
    [:param1, :param2, :param3].include? k
}.map {|k, v|
    [k, Array(v)[0]]
}.to_h
Model.where(**conditions)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do this?

```
def index
  @test = params.empty? ? Model.none : Model.where(params)
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried it but no luck. Please check updated question

Comment: What you're trying to do won't really play well. Based on your updated question, the fact that a single param can be passed twice results in an hash key pointing to an array, which you can't cleanly call with an ActiveRecord `where` query selection. Think about it in SQL: how would you write {:param1 => ["first", "second"]}? `WHERE param1 = 'first' AND param1 = 'second'` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I am parsing the params with CGI.parse so i am able to get the result for same param passed twice

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
def index
  par = params.slice(:param1, :param2, :param3).delete_if { |k, v| v.blank? }
  return if par.blank?
  Model.where(par)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. getting `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError` at `Model.where(params)`